# Web app that delegates a task with a return value in jms

Tags: spring, web, jms, activemq-classic

i am asked to create a 2 projects, project A and B, that makes use of JMS. B is a WEB project with a simple page containing a form where i input two dates(start date- end date). After submitting the form, B will ask A to process a task (Query a files) based on the two dates. B will then display the result in a web page. the caveat is that i need to do this in jms.

in my B controller im thinking about this (simplified. i'm using spring )

```
@controller
Mycontroller{
   MyMessageProducer mp;

   @RequestMapping(....)
   public String(...){

     mp.sendMessage(...);

    //wait for the response here and render?

   }    
}
```

now i'm stuck with how to implement project A. if a use a point-to-point messaging (using queue), then that means that A will have to explicitly get the message from the queue(im using activemq). Thats bad because A should be automatically listening for request, shouldn't it? However, if i use publisher-subscriber, in this case the publisher would be B, the client (because B sends message to A), which i think is a bad solution. which strategy should i use?

Now suppose that A successfully receives the message and query the file, how will i send the result back to B such the B will be able to display the result in a web page? is there a way to do this?

(PS i'm new to JMS though i've already implement a simple producers and receivers based on tutorials)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way, IMO, is to use [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/) which has the concept of [Gateways](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#gateway) (see also [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessagingGateway.html)). You can just specify a `service-interface` that has a method with a return value. Something like

```
public interface MessageProducer {
    @Gateway
    public String sendMessageAndGetReply(String name);
}
```

A proxy of the interface will be created. when you reference it from the `<int:gateway>` element. Something like

```
<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="replyChannel"/>

<int:gateway id="messageProducerGateway" default-request-channel="requestChannel"
    default-reply-channel="replyChannel"
    service-interface="demo.MessageProducer">
</int:gateway>

<int-jms:outbound-gateway id="outboundJmsGateway"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory" reply-channel="replyChannel"
    request-channel="requestChannel" reply-destination-name="reply.queue"
    request-destination-name="request.queue">
</int-jms:outbound-gateway>
```

The `<int-jms:outbound-gateway>` will send the message out the jms queue and receive a reply. `connectionFactory` is just your usual `ConnectionFactory` instances (i.e. `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`, `CachingConnectionFactory`)

On the "server" side of the jms interaction, you'll use a `<int-jms:inbound-gateway>`, Something like

```
<int-jms:inbound-gateway id="inboundJmsGateway"
    request-channel="requestChannel" acknowledge="client"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory" request-destination-name="request.queue" />

<int:service-activator id="messageHandler" ref="serverMessageHandler"
    input-channel="requestChannel">
</int:service-activator>
```

The `serverMessageHandler` is just a simple component with a method to handle and return a reply back to the gateway.

```
@Component
public class ServerMessageHandler {

    @ServiceActivator
    public String handleMessage(String message) {
        return "Hello, " + message;
    }
}
```

Running a simple demo

```
AbstractApplicationContext client = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("demo-gateway.xml");
AbstractApplicationContext server = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("demo-gateway-server.xml");
MessageProducer producer = client.getBean(MessageProducer.class);
String returnedMessage = producer.sendMessageAndGetReply("StackOverflow");
System.out.println(returnedMessage);
```

you get `"Hello, StackOverflow"`. There's not really much to it, once you get a basic understanding of the framework. The example I gave a synchronous example. You can see a full example (along with other examples) at [spring-integration-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) at github. I'd take some time to go over the reference guide to get familiar with the basics.